# Converting a .gif into a .swf using gif2swf

Tags: format-conversion

New to the forums, and the whole Ubuntu world, also NOT a technical person, so please be gracious.

Try as I might I cannot figure this thing out. Please keep in mind I know virtually NOTHING about how to run this thing (read: terminal). I just need to convert a .gif file I created into a flash (.swf) for my website. Here's what I typed (no laughing, ok maybe a little) and the response:

```
pandora@pandora-Satellite-L645:~$ gif2swf -o test.swf -r 12 animate.gif
Couldn't open animate.gif!
Error opening input file: animate.gif
No gif files found in arguments
```

I have a feeling it's something quite simple that I'm missing but like I said, total n00b. It took forever for me to even figure out I needed to type something.

Answer (score 1):

You run command in your home folder. But is file present exactly there?

Check if you home directory contains animate.gif. If not copy animate.gif to your homedir, or do `cd /path/to/file/` before run your command, or use full path: `gif2swf -o test.swf -r 12 /path/to/file/animate.gif`

Answer (score 1):

Does `animate.gif` actually exist?

Check if the directory you're currently in contains a file named `animate.gif` by running:

```
ls
```

This will list the contents of the current directory.

---

If you're in the wrong directory, change to the appropriate directory by running:

```
cd /path/to/correct/directory
```